# How can I get behavioursubject complate and error methods from server?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My service is like following:

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingService {
    private settings = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.loadSettings();
    }

    private loadSettings() {
        this.http.get<any[]>('/api/settings')
            .subscribe({
                 next: (settings) => this.settings.next(settings),
                 complete: () => this.settings.next,
                 error: (s) => this.settings.next(s)
             });
    }

    getSettings() {
        return this.settings.asObservable();
    }
}
```

And I am using this service in my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
   settings: any[];
   constructor(settingsService: SettingService){
     settingsService.getSettings().subscribe({
      next: components => {
        this.settings = settings;
      },
      error: (s) => {
        console.log("error.")
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log("complated.")
      }
    });

   }
}
```

But error or complate methods does not work in component. Only next method woks.

Comment: Why are you not just calling `loadSettings()` directly? It seems very odd to call this in the constructor then try and subscribe to it after the fact? `settingsService.loadSettings().subscribe(...)` would make much more sense and also get rid of the subscribe in `loadSettings` you don't need it

Comment: I have add, update, delete methods in my service and I am calling loadSettings() in there.

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference

Comment: what '/api/settings' returns from server ? json object ? what ?

Comment: yes  '/api/settings' returns json object from server.

Answer (score 1):

although you can just do that

```
   this.http.get<any[]>('/api/settings')
        .subscribe({
             next: (settings) => this.settings.next(settings),
             complete: () => this.settings.complete(),
             error: (s) => this.settings.error(s)
         });
```

but really you should just call loadSettings directly and assign property with it

```
settingsService.loadSettings().subscribe(res=>this.settings=res)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that your code should be like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingService {
    private settings = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.loadSettings();
    }

    private loadSettings() {
        this.http.get<any[]>('/api/settings')
            .subscribe(
              (settings) => this.settings.next(settings),
              (error) => console.error(error),
              () => console.log("I'm complete")
            );
            //.subscribe({
            //     next: (settings) => this.settings.next(settings),
            //     complete: () => this.settings.next,
            //     error: (s) => this.settings.next(s)
            // });
    }

    getSettings() {
        return this.settings.asObservable();
    }
}
```

and in the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
   settings: any[];

   constructor(settingsService: SettingService){ }

   ngOnInit() { 
     this.settingsService.getSettings().subscribe(
       (settings) => this.settings = settings
     );
   }

}
```

BTW: are you sure you receive Array ( [] ) and not an object ( {} ) from the server? if you receive an object you should change :

```
private settings = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
private settings = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

this.http.get<any[]>('/api/settings')
this.http.get<any>('/api/settings')

settings: any[];
settings: any;
```